# Circuit Build Times in Tor

Tags: relays, circuit

Why does Tor save the circuit build times and what does it want to learn out of them?
Tor loads the circuit build times from a file at the beginning. I do not know why it needs them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Circuit-Build-Times are measured and saved for the CircuitBuild-Timeouts. So Tor is logging the time it takes to build a Circuit. The CircuitBuild-Timeouts are then used to eliminate circuits which need excessive time to build.

The assumption is, that circuits, which need such a long time to be build, are more likely to be highly congested. So the purpose of not using slow-building-circuits, is get the better performance for the user as well as to relieve relays which are used to capacity.

CircuitBuild-Timeouts differ for every user because they depend on numerous factors (such as the local connection to the internet, the state of the tor-network, the state of the relays in the circuit and much more). This is why the 1000 most recent circuit build times are gathered and stored.

For more information read the [Path-Spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=path-spec.txt)